# p-element centralizing a Sylow p-subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, p-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $P$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup for a prime $p$ and
>   $g$ a $p$-element with $gxg^{-1} = x$ for all $x \in P$. Then $g \in Z(P)$.

Is this true? How can i prove that $g \in P$ ?

Comment: If it was not, then $\langle P,g\rangle$ would be a larger $p$-subgroup.

Comment: @ahulpke: I have $P \subseteq \left<P,g\right>$ and $\left<g\right> \subseteq \left<P,g\right>$, right?  But that would be true for any $g \in G$.  So I always could generate larger $p$-subgroups, for example with 2 different Sylow p-subgroups? So I definitely have something wrong in my understanding.  Besides from that I have $\left<P,g\right> = P\left<g\right>$ as $gx=xg$ for all $x \in P$.

Comment: @Boris: $P\langle g \rangle$ is a $p$-subgroup, since its order divides $|P| |\langle g \rangle|$. Since $P \leq P\langle g \rangle$ and $P$ is of maximal order among $p$-subgroups, it follows that $P = P \langle g \rangle$, and therefore $g \in P$. Since $g$ centralizes all elements of $P$, it's in $Z(P)$.

Comment: @Bungo: What if I have an arbitary set of p-elements. Is the subgroup generated by these p-elements not automatically a p-subgroup?

Comment: @Boris: No, consider any group $G$ which has at least two distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups, say $P$ and $Q$. Let $g \in Q \setminus P$. Then $\langle P, g\rangle$ properly contains $P$, and $P$ has maximal order among $p$-subgroups, so $\langle P, g\rangle$ cannot be a $p$-subgroup.

Comment: @Boris: For a concrete example, consider the symmetric group $S_3$. Take any two transpositions (elements with order $2$), and verify that they generate the whole group.

Comment: @Boris The crucial bit is that $g$ normalizes $P$, so the order of $\langle P,g\rangle$ divides $|P|\cdot|g|$ and thus is a $p$-power.

Answer (score 1):

In general the following holds:

**Proposition** Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ a prime dividing the order of $G$. If $P$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $S \in Syl_p(G)$, then $C_P(S)=P \cap Z(S)$.

**Proof** It is clear that any element of $P \cap Z(S)$ centralizes $S$. So assume $x \in C_P(S)$. Then $x$ centralizes $S$, whence $S\langle x \rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$. Since $x$ is a $p$-element, $|S\langle x \rangle|=\frac{|S| \cdot |\langle x \rangle|}{|S \cap \langle x \rangle|}$, which is a power of $p$. Since $S$ is Sylow, and $S \subseteq S\langle x \rangle$, it follows that in fact $S=S\langle x \rangle$. And this implies $x \in S$. But $x$ centralized $S$, meaning $x \in Z(S)$.

*Note*: one can prove the following useful similar statement for normalizers.

**Proposition** Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ a prime dividing the order of $G$. If $P$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $S \in Syl_p(G)$, then $N_P(S)=P \cap S.$